# How to install face-recognition in python

Tags: python, cmake

I tried for several hours to install `face-recognition` package use pip install with no success.

I was tried every tutorial on youtube and any post on stackoverflow,but most of them for linux (i use Windows 10), i already install visual studio cmake extension and install cmake but still with no sucess.

my commend :

```
pip install face-recognition==1.2.3
```

my error :

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rry20ka3'
       cwd: C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\
  Complete output (62 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:37:30) [MSC v.1927 32 bit (Intel)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\build\lib.win32-3.8'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe (found version "3.8.6")
  CMake Error at C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
    Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
    C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\elady\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, Click, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-owlzauu7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\
    Complete output (64 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:37:30) [MSC v.1927 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe (found version "3.8.6")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/elady/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ms3c_zpp/dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\elady\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\elady\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ms3c_zpp\\dlib_dacbba632c39475cafee67cef8852b96\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\elady\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-owlzauu7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\elady\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: pip install face-recognition

Comment: try deepface. it is keras based and easy to install and run. just run the command: pip install deepface.

Answer (score 1):

```
Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
```

Solution: Install and use the 32-bit `face-recognition` package.